# Error al procesar ETL

Tags: sql

He estado trabajando con business intelligence y al hacerlo con 1 una consulta simple eliminar y agregar funciona pero aveces visual presenta mensaje no responde, se cierra solo y se abre y al volver a procesar presenta mensaje de error y no entiendo el error, he tenido que empezar mil veces el proyecto y sigue ocurriendo ya sea cuando estoy terminando o cuando quiero ejecutarlo por segunda o tercera vez haber si va funcionando todo bien.

[image: Problema que presenta luego de ejecutar el ETL por segunda vez luego De que se haya cerrado solo.]

Comment: ¿Podrías poner la excepción que te da en texto? La imagen no siempre ayuda mucho. Con esto tu pregunta obtendrá mayor atención.